# [PHP Apache Shell], Permissao apache kill

Tags: php, apache, shell, centos

preciso matar um processo pelo `php`, porem utilizo `exec`, `system` ou `exec_shell` e não esta matando os processos, rodei na net e a galera esta falando que o apache não tem permissão pra executar esses tipos de comandos, o estranho é que estou logado como root no sistema  e mesmo assim não mata..
Alguém pode me ajudar ?

Comment: Você precisa adicionar o usuário www no grupo de super usuário. Utilize o comando addgroup www sudo

Comment: Como estou no CentOs esse comando nao existe

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo a sugestão do *touchmx*.

---

Verifique se o usuário www está no grupo correto.

Para ver os grupos:

```
groups
```

tente usar:

```
useradd -G {group-name} username
```

ou no caso:

```
useradd -G sudo www
```

Ou ainda:

```
useradd -G root www
```

---

Para maiores detalhes veja:
[How to Add User to root Group on CentOS 5/CentOS 6](http://www.ehowstuff.com/how-to-add-user-to-root-group-on-centos-5-7/)